# Dataset of researchers CV

Tags: data-request, usa, research

I'm looking for a dataset of researchers CV containing the following:

- date of all the main graduations (MS, PhD) and [change of ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_rank_in_the_United_States).
- location of their jobs
- their field
- their name and gender

I'm mostly interested in the US.

Comment: I put an answer here that can be tailored to search for researchers. http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/1924/1511 - It requires scraping but the data is well structured. For gender you can use: https://github.com/Bemmu/gender-from-name

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it would have all of what you're looking for, but there are a couple of efforts to try to give identifiers to researchers.  Most of them link to publications, and some have CV building tools.  They might not be 100% what you're looking for, but they may satisfice your need:

- http://orcid.org/
- http://researchgate.net/
- http://www.researcherid.com/

(note that I haven't looked at their terms for extracting their data; I know when I signed up for ORCID, it asked me what info I wanted to make public.)